# Long Response Time

Tags: apex, rest, callout

we have the integrations calling from salesforce to 1 system  to 2 system.

We wanted to check to if we could get some tool where we can measure the times from salesforce to 1 system only.

Is there any tool there to check or what can be done through code to measure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [module](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/module/event_monitoring) in Trailhead about Event Monitoring, maybe it will give you some ideas on how to proceed.